# Alternate mode menus in viewport by context

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, shortcut, pie-menu

Starting on v2.92 after 2.79. Almost zero familiarity with Blender, only occasional usage. Attempting to follow [Blender EEVEE: Glass Tutorial(Refraction)](https://youtu.be/elcYkXrkIE4?t=42) tutorial.

@0:45, the author seemingly uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up a circular *Pie Menu* is showing *Rendered*, *Wireframe*, *Solid* and *Material Preview* options.

However when I try to do the same, my *Pie Menu* instead displays: *Object Mode*, *Edit Mode*, *Sculpt Mode*, *Vertex Paint*, *Weight Paint* and *Texture Paint*.

How do I make my menu match the author's menu under those workflow circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That menu that you discribed:

> "Rendered," "Wireframe," "Solid," "Material Preview."

It is actually the shading menu, that appears on <kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: That works.  Thanks!